# Inline iteration key, value of object in array

Tags: coffeescript, iteration, inline

In coffeescript we can do this way:

```
rows = [
    {a: 1}
    {b: 2}
]

for row in rows
    for k,v of row
        alert "#{k}: #{v}"
```

So why we can't do that this way?:

```
for k,v of row for row in rows
    alert "#{k}: #{v}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it that way, but you can invert the inner loop and put the loop construct after the expression:

```
for row in rows
  alert "#{k}: #{v}" for k,v of row
```

And, as that inner loop is also an expression, you can also invert the outer loop the same way :D

```
alert "#{k}: #{v}" for k,v of row for row in rows
```

The most similar to what you were trying to write is probably this:

```
for row in rows then for k,v of row 
  alert "#{k}: #{v}"
```

Which can be further inlined using another `then` (the `then` keyword is usually equivalent to a newline and adding one level of indentation):

```
for row in rows then for k,v of row then alert "#{k}: #{v}"
```

All of these alternatives generate the same JS code, so picking one or another will not result on degraded performance or anything like that :D

Answer (score 0):

Because that compound syntax isn't part of the Coffeescript language.  Programming languages are not as fluid as human languages.

Comment: Question isn't about `fluid as human languages`. Python lambdas allow us to write more complicated expressions inline. Maybe iteration above can be written in CS but i didn't recognize how.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run `for k,v of row for row in rows` you get *Parse error on line 1: Unexpected 'FOR'*.

That's because the moment you put something before `for row in rows`, it must be an *expression*, and `for k,v of row` isn't one. You can verify this by making the prefixed loop an actual expression:

```
row for k,v of row for row in rows
```

This compiles. So, the same way you used the postfix form for iterating over `rows`, you have to postfix the inner one:

```
alert "#{k}: #{v}" for k,v of row for row in rows
```

To achieve the separation you want, you need to use `then` to replace newlines, instead of using a postfix expression:

```
for row in rows then for k,v of row
    alert "#{k}: #{v}"
```